# VS code error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

Tags: path, julia

[image: Error that shows up when executing code]

I downloaded VS code and was trying to run a particular julia code. I ran into this error that says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')". Now I have looked at a bunch of similar questions on here, but most of them pertains to remote accessing VS code (SSH) and that is not what I'm dealing with here. What have I done wrong here?

I saw from a link that it probably has to do with accessing Julia itself. I included the path directory to Julia under Settings. Under settings, it says that "Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the `julia.executablePath` setting points to the Julia binary.". I have the same path included in the User, Workspace, and src Folder

[image]

When I go back to my main code and run it, it says that the "Path to shell executable" does not exist. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The "Cannot read properties of undefined" error occurs with the JavaScript of VC Code when you try to access a property or a method on a variable that stores an undefined value. In this case, it is likely that a pathname associated with Julia is not defined or points to a file which does not exist.

The error is likely related to the message you quote as "Make sure the julia.executablePath setting points to the Julia binary." Check the pathname for Julia's binary. In particular, look at the path for improperly set slashes, drive names, or backslashes, since sometimes the path separator '/' or '\\' is not being used properly in your executablePath setting even if the Julia binary is where it should be.